# Mensaje de error para validar formulario PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

no puedo hacer que en el mensaje de error al guardar no me saque del formulario, si no que me deje en el formulario para corregir el error que pueda tener

```
        $obj->setUsuario_creacion("SIE");
        $obj->setUsuario_ultima_modificacion("SIE");
        $obj->setPantalla('AltaAcuerdos.php');
        if ($obj->Nuevo_juridico()) {
            echo "Registro guardado correctamente";
        } else {
            echo 'Error al guardar';
        } break;
```

ya que cuando le doy en el boton aceptar del mensaje de error me saca del formulario y me lleva a la otra pagina definida en este codigo

```
   $.confirm({
          icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',
          title: 'Confirmación',
          content: data,
          type: 'dark',
          typeAnimated: true,
          buttons:
            {
               aceptar:
                  {
                      btnClass: 'btn-dark',
                      action: function () {
                           //$("#formEjes")[0].reset();
                               window.location.href ="Lista_juridico.php?nombreUsuario="+$("#usuario").val() + $("#nombreUsuario").val() + "&tipoPerfil=" + $("#tipoPerfil").val() + "&idUsuario=" + $("#idUsuario").val();
                             }
                      }
                  }
           });

       } else {
          // swal(data,'','error');
         // $("#mensajes").html(data);
       $.confirm({
           icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
           title: 'Error',
           content: data,
           type: 'red',
           typeAnimated: true,
           buttons:
   {
          aceptar:

               btnClass: 'btn-dark',
               action: function () {
                                       
                    }
                 }
            }
       });
}
```

esta parte es con AJAX y JS

Comment: no puedes usar un getch();

Comment: ?nombreUsuario="+$("#usuario").val() + $("#nombreUsuario").val()   Está cierto de ese?  No debe ser ?Usuario="+$("#usuario").val()+ "&nombreUsario=" + $("#nombreUsuario").val()

Answer (score 0):

Usando Ajax y JQuery yo lo haría de esta manera.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Lista_juridico.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { //Aquí pones los datos que quieres enviar
            nombreUsuario: $("#usuario").val() + $("#nombreUsuario").val(),
            tipoPerfil: $("#tipoPerfil").val(),
            idUsuario: $("#idUsuario").val()
        },
        success: function (result){
            if(result == 'Registro guardado correctamente'){
               //Aquí entra si no hay errores
            }else if(result == 'Error al guardar'){
                //Aquí entra si hay un error, puedes señalizar donde está el, error por ejemplo.
            }
        }
    });
```